# Azure CLI can't create folders outside home folder

Tags: permission-denied, istio, azure-aks

I am running my application on AKS, and have istio on top of kubernetes to add extra control over the services. However for controlling https request at the istio  ingress level, I need to specify a key and certificates. To do this, according to istio traffic docs, we required to have the two files in the /etc folder. When I try to create any files outside my home directory, it gives me a permission denied. I tried chmod change and tried to change the user to root. Currently when I check the user id, it gives 95** (so not root). Is there a way to get root access or an alternate way to control https in istio. [The Image shows the istio yaml file where I need to add the /etc/istio/files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aaWRP.png)

Comment: FYI: According to the istio docs, this location and filenames cannot be changed.

Comment: you dont need to put those files on that path. I've been running istio from inside home folder and it works fine on Azure Cloud Shell

Comment: I got it working by following this guide, https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/secure-ingress/. And to resolve the permission issue, I created a ubuntu vm of my own where i have root access, and applied the changes there. I have azure cluster connection between my vm and the aks, so it got reflected without any permission issues.

Comment: doesnt make sense. i got it working from cloud shell